# Как обновить GUI для WPF приложения (MVVM) с помощью DataBinding и данных из другого потока?

Tags: wpf, многопоточность, gui, mvvm

Приступил к изучению потоков и решил проверить полученные знания на простеньком приложении. Делаю в WPF по MVVM примитивный секундомер. В GUI есть текстбокс, где отображается и кнопка запуска\остановки, которая меняет вид в зависимости от того, работает секундомер или нет.
ViewModel файл в отдельном классе, его задача обновлять открытое свойство DisplayTime, куда записывается время из секундомера в этом классе реализован интерфейс OnPropertyChanged.

Сам секундомер на основе Stopwatch класса в  отдельном файле (Model). В нем я сделал событие, которое срабатывает 60 раз в секунду, Дисплей подписан на это событие и при срабатывании обновляет свойство DisplayTime, и уведомляет об изменении в OnProperty Changed.

MainWindow и текстбокс для отображения связан с помощью DataBinding.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при такой реализации правильно создать поток для секундомера, и чтобы свойство обновлялось с помощью DataBinding.

Я посмотрел разные туториалы с BackgroundWorker, попытался применить то, что там было сказано, но получается просто создать поток, но я не понимаю как им управлять, не смотря на то, что код самого секундомера работает, GUI не обновляется. К тому же все примеры, всю логику приложений делали в MainWindow.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Display display;
    private bool isRunning = false;
    

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = display;
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isRunning)
        {
            startButtonText.Text = "Start";
            isRunning = false;
            display.StartTimer();
        }
        else if(!isRunning)
        {
            startButtonText.Text = "Stop";
            display.StopTimer();
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь только логика работы кнопки. Я, честно, теряюсь как правильно создать поток.

Это код ViewModel дисплея

```
    internal class Display : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    string displayTimer;
    private bool isRunning;
    
    private StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();

    public Display()
    {
        DisplayTimer = "0:00:00";
        stopWatch.timeStamp += UpdateTimer;
    }

    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get { return isRunning; }
    }

    public string DisplayTimer
    {
        get { return displayTimer; }
        set { displayTimer = value; OnPropertyChange(nameof(DisplayTimer)); }
    }

    private void UpdateTimer(TimeSpan ts)
    {
        DisplayTimer = String.Format($"{ts.Minutes:00}:{ts.Seconds:00}:{ts.Milliseconds:00}");
    }


    public void StartTimer()
    {
        isRunning = true;
        stopWatch.EnableTimer();
       
    }
    public void StopTimer()
    {
        isRunning = false;
        stopWatch.DisableTimer();
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Это код самого секундомера

```
     internal class StopWatch
{
    private Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    private int delay;

    private bool isEnabled;
    private TimeSpan timespan;

    public StopWatch()
    {
        
        delay = 16;
    }

    public StopWatch(int delay)
    {
        Delay = delay;
    }

    public int Delay
    {
        get { return delay; }
        set { delay = value; }
    }
    public void EnableTimer()
    {
        isEnabled = true;
        double timer = delay;
        
        sw.Start();

        while (isEnabled)
        {
            TimeSpan t1 = sw.Elapsed;
            TimeSpan t2 = sw.Elapsed;
            timespan = t2 - t1;
            
            timer -= timespan.Milliseconds;
            if (timer <= 0)
            {
                timespan = sw.Elapsed;
                timeStamp?.Invoke(timespan);
                timer = delay;
            }
        }
    }

    public void DisableTimer()
    {
        isEnabled = false;
        sw.Stop();
    }

    public delegate void TimeStampHandler(TimeSpan ts);
    public event TimeStampHandler timeStamp;
}
```

Код секундомера работает. Его реализация может вызывать вопросы, но мне нужно прежде всего понять, как заставить его обновлять GUI.
Вопросы по этой теме были тут но все примеры, что я видел были с кодом в главном окне.

Comment: У вас в коде очень много лишнего, начиная от `BackgroundWorker` (который не нужен), заканчивая нарушениями MVVM. 1. `BackgroundWorker` - как я и сказал ранее, он вам не нужен по одной простой причине - вам не нужны потоки, вам нужна асинхронность... К тому же, `BackgroundWorker` не используют уже очень давно, ибо если надо сделать свой поток, то он и делается, зачем эта обертка? 2. У вас в коде много мест, где вы делаете лишнюю работу, например `DisplayTimer = String.Format(...);` - почему это делаете вы, а не View слой (XAML)? 3. У вас нарушен MVVM, как минимум тем, что окно отвечает за VM.

Comment: `Button_Click` - тоже не должно у вас быть (должны быть `ICommand` (команды)), забудьте вообще про события контролов, а также `x:Name` в XAML и дальнейшем обращение в коде через имена контролов. `Stopwatch` - как по мне тоже не лучший вариант, не зря он находится в пространстве имен `System.Diagnostics`, намекая нам на то, что это инструмент диагностики.

Comment: BackgroundWorker - это остаток от предыдущей версии, кода я весь день занимаюсь переделкой, и местами могут быть мусорные строки. Я еще раз прошу, не обращайте на реализацию приложения. Мой стаж в программировании несколько месяцев, я учу параллельно синтаксис и WPF. Я читал, что нужно использовать Icommand, но Intellisense на моем VS их не отображает, поэтому мне пока проще и быстрее обрабатывать кнопки. Далее Stopwatch я использовал, просто потому что, если искать статьи, какие таймеры использовать будет очень много рекоммендаций использовать его, потому что он точный

Comment: `не отображает` - что? В XAML? Укажите `d:DataContext` окну на тип VM слоя, будет вам подсказывать. Вы ведь учитесь, так учитесь сразу правильно, ибо сейчас у вас ИМХО, нет MVVM, это просто код, кривоватый код с кучей лишнего. А вот дальше уже думайте, что с этим делать, писать и дальше "криво", или понять и сразу использовать все как надо. По поводу вопроса - я лично не понял вашего вопроса, ибо вопрос у вас "Как создать поток" - ответ я вам дал "Он вам не нужен", а если хотите всеж поток, то смотрите класс `Thread`, а не `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: Я использовал BackgroundWorker, потому что с Thread не вышло, когда стал искать информацию, то узнал, что в WPF нельзя обращаться к данным из других потоков(что бы это ни значило), и нужно использовать Backgroundworker и какой-то маршаллинг с диспетчером.

Comment: Вы ведь понимаете, что сейчас просто оправдываетесь, а не пытаетесь решить поставленную задачу/проблемы?) Мне лично без разницы почему там это вы написали, я лишь сказал вам прямым текстом, где конкретно вижу в вашем коде проблемные места, вот и все, хотите с ими идти дальше - дерзайте, нет - спрашивайте, что именно не понятно, будем разбираться. А то я вам "У вас проблема", а в ответ "А это потому что я так захотел"... ну ок, захотели, а дальше что?

Comment: Спасибо за вашу помощь.